# Count in prolog - Impossible to do

Tags: prolog

EDIT : More simple :

I changed my code to simplify. A predicate "nbarret" return the numbers of stations i want.

So there is my new code, but it doesn't change anything :

```
nb_stations([],0).
nb_stations([S,Li,Dir,SS],X):-nbarret(Li,S,SS,Dir,Y),X is X1 + Y.
nb_stations([S,Li,Dir,SS|Tr],X):-
     nbarret(Li,S,SS,Dir,Y),nb_stations([SS|Tr],X is X1 + Y).
```

In this case, i have an error :

```
ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
Exception: (8) (_G2031 is _G2270+1)is _G2711+5 ? creep
Exception: (7) nb_stations([charles_de_gaulle_etoile, m6, nation, bir_hakeim], _G2031 is _G2270+1) ? creep
Exception: (6) nb_stations([la_defense, rerA, vincennes, charles_de_gaulle_etoile, m6, nation, bir_hakeim], _G2031) ? creep
```

/-------------------------------------------------------------/

Old code (deprecated, i keep for comprehension) :

```
nb_stations([S,Li,Dir,SS|Tr],X):-num_stations(S,Li,Dir1,ND,_,_),Dir=Dir1,!,
num_stations(SS,Li,Dir1,NA,_,_),Dir=Dir1,!,
calculer(ND,NA,Y),X is X1 + Y,nb_stations([SS|Tr],X).

nb_stations([S,Li,Dir,SS|Tr],X):-num_stations(S,Li,_,_,Dir2,ND),!,
num_stations(SS,Li,_,_,Dir2,NA),!,
Dir=Dir2,!,calculer(ND,NA,Y),X is X1 + Y,nb_stations([SS|Tr],X).

calculer(ND,NA,X):-X is ND - NA.
```

More Details :

When you call nb_stations, you have to inform a path in a List, with the departure station, the lign of the transport, the direction, and then the station you will stop. If we have more next, it will be the correspondence. In this example :    nb_stations([la_defense,rerA,vincennes,charles_de_gaulle_etoile,m6,nation,bir_hakeim],X).

You start in la_defense, you take the "rerA" transport, and you take "vincennes" for the direction. Then you stop in "charles_de_gaulle_etoile", and you take the m6 (metro), the direction is "nation", and you are arrived in "bir_hakeim". So my code count the number of stations i pass in this travel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the order when X is assigned.

```
nb_stations([S,Li,Dir,SS|Tr],X):-
    num_stations(S,Li,Dir1,ND,_,_),
    Dir=Dir1,!,
    num_stations(SS,Li,Dir1,NA,_,_),
    Dir=Dir1,!,
    calculer(ND,NA,Y),
    nb_stations([SS|Tr],X1),
    X is X1 + Y.   % Change here

nb_stations([S,Li,Dir,SS|Tr],X):-
    num_stations(S,Li,_,_,Dir2,ND),!,
    num_stations(SS,Li,_,_,Dir2,NA),!,
    Dir=Dir2,!,
    calculer(ND,NA,Y),
    nb_stations([SS|Tr],X1),
    X is X1 + Y. % Change here
```

Comment: I have the same error with your code, it didn't understand how is X1 and X. For him: X1 is X + Y is > _G1673 is _G1546+1. 

I just want to have X = 5 for example, at the end, but when i start X equal nothing.

Comment: I've edited the code. It seems that you need a clause for a trivial case; please explain in more detail what your code needs to do and I'll try to help.

Comment: Did you try just changing the order of `nb_stations([SS|Tr],X1)` and `X is X1 + Y` like I did above? X1 is uninstantiated in your code.

Comment: I simplified my code :) i edited my post. I have the same error than before, i see what i want > (_G2031 is _G2270+1)is _G2711+5, 5+1 but the operation not done.

Comment: In your new code, line 2: X1 is still uninstantiated (no value), it doesn't get defined anywhere. Line 4 should probably be something like: `nbarret(Li,S,SS,Dir,Y),nb_stations([SS|Tr],X1), X is X1 + Y.`

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to write exactly ?

```
nb_stations([S,Li,Dir,SS|Tr],X):-
     num_stations(S,Li,_,_,Dir2,ND),!,
     num_stations(SS,Li,_,_,Dir2,NA),!,
     Dir=Dir2,!,
     calculer(ND,NA,Y),
     nb_stations([SS|Tr],X is X1+Y).
```

May be

```
nb_stations([S,Li,Dir,SS|Tr],X):-
     num_stations(S,Li,_,_,Dir2,ND),!,
     num_stations(SS,Li,_,_,Dir2,NA),!,
     Dir=Dir2,!,
     calculer(ND,NA,Y),

     X is X1 + Y,  <== here X1 is a free variable

     nb_stations([SS|Tr],X).
```

Comment: I just want to recup two numbers, substract and add in X:
Example : ND - NA -> 15-10 and i want to add in X, so X = 5. And each time add to X results.

I had an error when i tried your code (see my post, i edited it^^ )